# populating arraylist with maps

Tags: java, excel, dictionary, arraylist, spreadsheet

I am taking data from an excel spread sheet and am trying to add each row to a map and then put that map into an array list how ever it is only putting the last row in multiple times This is the code that I have:

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();           
            Map<String,Object> cells = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            table(cells,rowIterator,list);
public ArrayList table(Map<String,Object> cells, Iterator<Row> rowIterator,ArrayList list) throws Exception
    {
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            //For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if(cell.getRowIndex()>=1){

                    //cell = cellIterator.next();
                    Object obj = null;
                    switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        obj = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        System.out.print((boolean)obj + "\t\t\t");

                        cells.put(columnName(cell.getColumnIndex()),obj);
                        list.add(cells);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        obj = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.print((String)obj + "\t\t\t");

                        cells.put(columnName(cell.getColumnIndex()),obj);
                        list.add(cells);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        obj = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                        System.out.print((double)obj+ "\t\t\t");

                        cells.put(columnName(cell.getColumnIndex()),obj);
                        list.add(cells);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        obj = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.print((String)obj + "\t\t\t");

                        cells.put(columnName(cell.getColumnIndex()),obj);
                        list.add(cells);
                        break;
                    }


                }

            }

            System.out.println("");


        }

        return list;
    }
```

the array list should have

> [{userid=1, name=dave},{userid=2, name=terry}]

inside of it how ever what is actually in side is

> [{userid=2, name=terry},{userid=2, name=terry},{userid=2, name=terry},{userid=2, name=terry},{userid=2, name=terry},{userid=2, name=terry},{userid=2, name=terry}]

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem ist this line:

```
cells.put(columnName(cell.getColumnIndex()),obj);
```

you overrides all values with last row, because `cell.getColumnIndex())` is identical for each row.

and `list.add(cell);` adds it not one time for each cell and not row

to avoid it use `Map<Integer,Map<String, Object>>` is that waht you need or use new map foreach row.

Second approach:

```
 while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
   Row row = rowIterator.next();
   cells = new HashMap<>();
```

...

Comment: So how can i get a key for each value?

Comment: @TomRodd i thing the second approach is what you need